# Opening Settings option inside Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, operating-system

How do i programmatically open USB Debugging Option, or atleast give hint like android system does it?
[Here is an Idea about the system hint I mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZdXL.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't.** The setting you want to enable by programming is only user action based setting. Means when the user enables it by themself from developer mode, then and only then it will be enabled else it will stay disabled. Android does not provide a way to achieve you want, as it can become a huge security issue for android device. By default, the setting is disabled in android framework, Here is why

> USB Debugging allows an Android device to communicate with a computer running the Android SDK to use advanced operations.